# Pass a Single ID from a for loop to another Activity in android?

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent

I have a row as shown in figure. the row is in for loop. So now depending on the response No. of rows get increased . I am having `View` as a button and `onclick` of that I want to open a new activity which will pass the ID of that Index. I get the IDs in a `String Array`.With every Row I get a ID , Now I just want that When users clicks on any View, corresponding ID should get passed to new activity.
Say Like `FB SDK` has a Seperate ID, `Ford Escape` has a seperate ID , Depending on the click of user corresponding ID only get passed to another activity. 
I have the IDs in a `String array`.
    `

```
for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject= jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Name[i]=jsonObject.getString("Name");
                    Attachments[i]=jsonObject.getString("attachments");
                    ProjID[i]=jsonObject.getString("ProjectID");

                    View v = new View(getApplicationContext());
                    v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                //  v.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
                    //v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams());            
                    t1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                //  t2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    t3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                b1= new Button(getApplicationContext());

                    t1.setText(Name[i]);
                    if(Name[i].contains("null")){
                        t1.setText("");
                    }
                    t1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    //t2.setText("View");
                    b1.setText("View");
                    b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                //  t2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    t3.setText("View");
                    t3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);



                    /*if(Attachments[i].contains("null")){
                        t3.setText("");
                    }*/

                    t1.setTextSize(15);
                    //t2.setTextSize(15);
                    b1.setTextSize(15);
                    t3.setTextSize(15);

                    t1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                //  t2.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                    t3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                    t1.setWidth(50 * dip);
                    //t2.setWidth(50 * dip);
                    t3.setWidth(50 * dip);

                    t1.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                //  t2.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
                    t3.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);

                    row.addView(t1);
                    row.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 20);
                //  row.addView(t2);
                    row.addView(b1);
                    row.addView(t3);

                    listd.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    listd.addView(v);


            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                //String m_myData[];
                //int i=0;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("IDS are:", ProjID[0]);

                    //Bundle bundel = new Bundle();
                 // for(int j=0;j<ProjID.length;j++){
                //      bundel.putStringArray("ID", ProjID);    

                //  }


                //  Intent intent =new Intent(List.this,peoplelist.class);
                    //bundel.putStringArray("IDs", ProjID);
                    //startActivity(intent);

                }
            });`
```

[image]

Comment: Are the rows saved in a ListView?

Comment: No, those are in a table layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use a ListView for this. It will make your life easier.
Keeping the current structure, you can do as follows:

`b1.setTag(<TheIdYouWantToPassLater>);`

In OnClickListener:

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

   String projId = v.getTag();
   Intent intent =new Intent(List.this,peoplelist.class);
   intent.putExtra("IDs", projId);
   startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Hope it helps.